# Flat File select values from array

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference, array-intersect

I have Flat File with data separated by "," i need compare the values with url and show only the values with the same values of url

**No need CSV function of PHP , i want compare and get the results if when compare with the values from url finally are the same**

The csv have 4 values , price , size , width and height

The URL values , send other values but in the same order (price, size, width and heigt), for example in the url i send this using strings index.php?price=100&size=100&width=200&height=300 ...... , etc

For example :

```
<?php

    $csv_file=file("test.csv");

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($csv_file);$i++) {

    $exp_csv=explode(",",$csv_file[$i]);

    foreach($exp_csv as $exp_csv2) {
        $csv_end_values[]=$exp_csv2
    }

}


/// By Other side the url 

$exp_url="100,30,400,500";

$exp_url_values=explode(",",$exp_url);


foreach($exp_url_values as $exp_url_values2) {
    $url_end_values[]=$exp_url_values2;
}


/// Finally we have 2 arrays one array with all values we 
get in bucle for csv and by other side values get from url , 
now we need compare url values with values of csv , 
for example if in the url we have only 2 values and no 4 show 
only results with the same of 2 values from url and compare 
in the same order , if when compare the values no the same all , get 0 results 


/// For example values from URL 100,,200,, 
if in csv exists one row with the values 100 and 200 
in the same order show as result and if no , no show 


/// In this point i try use array_difference , 
but no works , because i need compare all values i send by 
url and in the same order 


$aa = array_diff($url_end_values,csv_end_values);


$num_results=0;

foreach($aa as $bb) {
    $num_results++;
}


if ($num_results==0) {
    print "We get Results";
}
else {
    print "No Results";
}

?>
```

Comment: PHP has a function for getting CSV values and dealing with them: fgetcsv(); Check it out!

Comment: No need this csv function i need compare values i get with url , please read my post please

Comment: Ive read your post, and first of all, you are making it WAY to complicated to get the array you want. ASwell im not sure if you got the array you want. you need a $key => $value array, in order to compare it - you only got an array where you got all values, but you have 0 sense what value is matched to what key. You should realy check fgetcsv() out.

Comment: AS you can see in the post i get the values from url and values from csv , no problem , the problem it´s compare values from url in the same order with the values of flat file or csv and get results if the values the same

Comment: What you want is just compare the url? Like what is the difference between index.php?price=100&size=100 and index.php?price=150&size=200?

Comment: Yes Bryan , the url send values , i get this values and compare with the values from csv file or flat file , i extract values from csv and from url and compare and finally i need only show the values with the same values of url

Comment: Ok , nice  , can you put here ?

Comment: Honestly, you don't understand. YES you have an array with values. But you have ABSOLUTELY NO sense without the keys from the csv. You need a $key => $value array.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you want, the function I made just compares the strings of urls with get parameter, not csv. Like index.php?price=100&size=100 and index.php?price=150&size=200, the difference will be price=150 & price=100 and size=200 & size=100.

Comment: yes its the same i want

Answer (score 1):

Use fgetcsv (http://php.net/fgetcsv) to read the CSV file instead of normal file method. You will get the array format and it will be much easier to compare from your URL query string.

Comment: Please read my post , no need csv functions for get values , i need compare this values with values from url

Comment: @user3626084: Read the linked man page: use the right tool for the job! you are reading a csv file, use the functions that were especially created for that type of file, then!

Answer (score 0):

This is based on what I understand that you really want.

```
$link1 = "index.php?price=150&size=200";
$link2 = "index.php?price=100&size=100";

// separate the string by ampersand to get the get parameters.
$link1ParamsRaw = explode('&',substr(stristr($link1, '?'),1)); // the second param removes all strings from start to ?
$link2ParamsRaw = explode('&',substr(stristr($link2, '?'),1));

$link1Params = array();
$link2Params = array();

foreach($link1ParamsRaw as $param) {
    $param = explode('=',$param); // separate key from value                 
    $link1Params[$param[0]] = $param[1]; // assuming all keys have values
}

foreach($link2ParamsRaw as $param) {
    $param = explode('=',$param); // separate key from value                 
    $link2Params[$param[0]] = $param[1]; // assuming all keys have values
}

$differences = array_diff_assoc($link1Params, $link2Params);

var_dump($differences);
```